# Is Dark Energy and or Dark Matter directly proportional to EMR?

Tags: energy, dark-matter, dark-energy

Is Dark Energy directly proportional to Electromagnetic radiation (EM radiation or EMR)?

Comment: This appears to be asking for opinions on reading a book. Also, what is EMR?

Comment: Question: "Is DE directly proportional to EMR"?

Comment: You also have *Is this a good book to read, "The Magnetic Universe"?* there as well

Comment: Thank You, I made a search and all I came up with was the book? "This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers."

Comment: Also, have you read the [Wikipedia entry on dark energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_energy)?

Comment: Yes, I understand the equation of state (the relationship between temperature, pressure, and combined matter, energy, and vacuum energy density for any region of space).

Comment: Please indicate what you mean by "proportional to radiation", and why you think it could be. Currently it is unclear where this question comes from.

Answer (score 2):

No-one knows what dark energy is, but we can be fairly sure it is not related in any way to the electromagnetic force for the simple reason that dark energy is uniformly distributed and charged matter is not. If the two were related we would expect some correlation between them.

Incidentally, [The Magnetic Universe](http://www.amazon.co.uk/The-Magnetic-Universe-Elusive-Invisible/dp/080189302X) is an excellent book about cosmological magnetic fields, but is not concerned with dark energy.

Comment: Radiant energy is the energy of electromagnetic radiation. 
Is radiant energy uniformly distributed?